# Application Insights Summarize with Having clause

Tags: azure-application-insights

I need to summarize an Application Insights query where the count > 1.  I don't see any "Having" clause like SQL has.  How can I limit my query to only include records when count > 1?

```
traces
| extend MessageId = tostring(customDimensions.MessageId) 
| summarize Count = count() by MessageId 
| order by Count desc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've called the summarize function Count is treated as a column so you can use a where clause to filter it:

```
traces
| extend MessageId = tostring(customDimensions.MessageId) 
| summarize Count = count() by MessageId 
| where Count > 1
| order by Count desc
```